# How would I add the data from one class to another class' JTable, by JButton?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, tablemodel

what I am trying to do is to do store input data from user using array/arraylist then display it on a JTable. I have two different dialogs/classes for the Jtable and another dialog for user input so when they click JButtonAdd, it will automatically display the data on the JTbale that is on the other dialog/class. I am complete clueless on how to do it. Here are the codes I came up so far.

```js
**MAIN Program**



import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class StartProgram extends JDialog {
 private JTable tableInfo;

 /**
  * Launch the application.
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     StartProgram dialog = new StartProgram();
     dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }

 /**
  * Create the dialog.
  */
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public StartProgram() {
  getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(153, 255, 153));
  setBounds(100, 100, 550, 500);
  getContentPane().setLayout(null);
  
  JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
  btnDelete.setBounds(379, 11, 145, 23);
  btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to delete?");
   }
  });

  getContentPane().add(btnDelete);
  
  JButton btnAddQueueNumber = new JButton("Add Queue Number");
  btnAddQueueNumber.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    AddQueueNumber dialog = new AddQueueNumber();
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
   }
  });
  btnAddQueueNumber.setBounds(10, 11, 145, 23);
  getContentPane().add(btnAddQueueNumber);
  
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
  scrollPane.setBounds(10, 45, 514, 405);
  getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
  
  tableInfo = new JTable();
  tableInfo.setShowGrid(false);
  scrollPane.setViewportView(tableInfo);
  tableInfo.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
   new Object[][] {
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null},
   },
   new String[] {
    "Queue Number", "Name", "Interviewer", "Time", "Room"
   }
  ) {
   boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
    false, false, false, false, false
   };
   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return columnEditables[column];
   }
  });
  
  JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
  btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Search dialog = new Search();
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
   }
  });
  btnSearch.setBounds(164, 11, 145, 23);
  getContentPane().add(btnSearch);

 }
}
```

**AddQueueNumber Class**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class AddQueueNumber extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField tfQueueNumber;
    private JTextField tfName;
    private JTextField tfInterviewer;
    private JTextField tfTime;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AddQueueNumber dialog = new AddQueueNumber();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public AddQueueNumber() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 270, 235);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblQueueNumber = new JLabel("Queue Number");
        lblQueueNumber.setBounds(10, 11, 93, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblQueueNumber);

        tfQueueNumber = new JTextField();
        tfQueueNumber.setBounds(98, 8, 146, 20);
        contentPanel.add(tfQueueNumber);
        tfQueueNumber.setColumns(10);

        tfName = new JTextField();
        tfName.setBounds(98, 39, 146, 20);
        contentPanel.add(tfName);
        tfName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name");
        lblName.setBounds(10, 42, 78, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblName);

        tfInterviewer = new JTextField();
        tfInterviewer.setBounds(98, 70, 146, 20);
        contentPanel.add(tfInterviewer);
        tfInterviewer.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblInterviewer = new JLabel("Interviewer");
        lblInterviewer.setBounds(10, 73, 78, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblInterviewer);

        tfTime = new JTextField();
        tfTime.setBounds(98, 101, 146, 20);
        contentPanel.add(tfTime);
        tfTime.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblTime = new JLabel("Time");
        lblTime.setBounds(10, 104, 78, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblTime);

        JComboBox cbRoom = new JComboBox();
        cbRoom.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {" ", "Circle Room", "Square Room", "Triangle Room", "Pentagon Room", "Rectangle Room"}));
        cbRoom.setBounds(98, 132, 146, 20);
        contentPanel.add(cbRoom);

        JLabel lblRoom = new JLabel("Room");
        lblRoom.setBounds(10, 135, 78, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblRoom);
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
                okButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        //This is where the data will be saved on the JTable
                        JTable tableInfo = new JTable();
                        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tableInfo.getModel();
                        if (!tfQueueNumber.getText().trim().equals ("")){
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{ tfQueueNumber.getText(), tfName.getText(),tfInterviewer.getText(), cbRoom.getSelectedItem().toString(),tfTime.getText() });
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Queue number should not be blank!");
                        }
                    }
                });
                okButton.setActionCommand("Add");
                buttonPane.add(okButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);

            }
            {
                JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancelButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        dispose();
                    }
                });
                cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
                buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am complete clueless on how to do it"* Review your course notes and text.   *"Need a lot of help since my professor is not that good of a teacher. :)"*  It's a poor student that blames the teacher.  But in any case, SO is not the place for recruiting a tutor, or for that general level of help.  Voting to close.

Comment: thanks.. i know that was a bit too much but it was overwhelming for me to create this project with the less knowledge i knew about programming since i just started 3 months ago. thanks and more power..

Answer (score 2):

Start by defining a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) which describes the data you are trying to capture...

```
public class Interview {

    private int queueNumber;
    private String name;
    private String interviewer;
    private Date time;
    private String room;

    public Interview(int queueNumber, String name, String interviewer, Date time, String room) {
        this.queueNumber = queueNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.interviewer = interviewer;
        this.time = time;
        this.room = room;
    }

    public String getInterviewer() {
        return interviewer;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQueueNumber() {
        return queueNumber;
    }

    public String getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setQueueNumber(int queueNumber) {
        this.queueNumber = queueNumber;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setInterviewer(String interviewer) {
        this.interviewer = interviewer;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setRoom(String room) {
        this.room = room;
    }



}
```

This will allow you to encapsulate the data into simple to manage container.  I personally prefer to use `interface`s for this as it allows me better control over what to expose and what functionality to make available, but we'll keep it simple here...

Create a `JPanel` which can act as an editor for interview details...

```
public class InterviewPane extends JPanel {

    private JSpinner queueNumber;
    private JTextField name;
    private JTextField interviewer;
    private JSpinner time;
    private JComboBox room;

    private Interview interview;

    public InterviewPane(Interview interview) {
        this();
        this.interview = interview;
        if (interview != null) {
            queueNumber.setValue(interview.getQueueNumber());
            time.setValue(interview.getTime());
            name.setText(interview.getName());
            interviewer.setText(interview.getInterviewer());
            room.setSelectedItem(interview.getRoom());
        }
    }

    public InterviewPane() {
        queueNumber = new JSpinner();
        time = new JSpinner();
        SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.MINUTE);
        time = new JSpinner(sm);
        JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(time, "hh:mm a");
        name = new JTextField(10);
        interviewer = new JTextField(10);
        room = new JComboBox();
        room.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{" ", "Circle Room", "Square Room", "Triangle Room", "Pentagon Room", "Rectangle Room"}));

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(new JLabel("Queue Number: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Name: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Interviewer: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Time: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Room: "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(queueNumber, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(name, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(interviewer, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(time, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(room, gbc);
    }

    public Interview getInterview() {

        Interview result = interview;

        if (result == null) {
            result = new Interview(
                        (Integer)queueNumber.getValue(), 
                        name.getText(), 
                        interviewer.getText(), 
                        (Date)time.getValue(), 
                        (String)room.getSelectedItem());

        } else {

            interview.setInterviewer(interviewer.getText());
            interview.setName(name.getText());
            interview.setTime((Date) time.getValue());
            interview.setRoom((String) room.getSelectedItem());
            interview.setQueueNumber((int) queueNumber.getValue());

        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

This allows you the ability to decide when and where to use the editor pane, as a general practice you should avoid extending directly from top level containers like `JDialog`

Now, when you want to display the editor you can use something like...

```
InterviewPane editor = new InterviewPane();
switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmationDialog(this, editor, "Details", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)) {
    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
        Interview interview = editor.getInterview();
        break;
}
```

This will allow you to get the details from the editor based on the user response.

Note, you will probably want to use an `AbstractTableModel` instead of a `DefaultTableModel` as it's easier to manage `POJO`s

Take a look at:

- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

For more details.

You should avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

**Updated**

Swing uses a version of the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm.  This means that there is a separation between the UI (view) and the data (model).

This means, that when you want to change what's on the screen, you only need to change the model and not the whole UI.

For example, in this case, I would use a `AbstractTableModel` to base my `TableModel` on and provide the functionality I need (like the ability to add/remove `Interview` objects).  This keeps the `Interview` intact and makes it much easier to manage generally

```
public class InterviewTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    protected static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
        "Queue Number", "Name", "Interviewer", "Time", "Room"
    };

    protected static final Class[] COLUMN_TYPES = new Class[]{
        Integer.class, String.class, String.class, Date.class, String.class
    };

    private List<Interview> rows;

    public InterviewTableModel() {
        rows = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void addInterview(Interview interview) {
        rows.add(interview);
        int rowIndex = rows.size() - 1;
        fireTableRowsInserted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    public void removeInterview(Interview interview) {
        if (rows.contains(interview)) {
            int rowIndex = rows.indexOf(interview);
            rows.add(interview);
            fireTableRowsInserted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return COLUMN_TYPES[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Interview interview = rows.get(rowIndex);
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = interview.getQueueNumber();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = interview.getName();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = interview.getInterviewer();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = interview.getTime();
                break;
            case 4:
                value = interview.getRoom();
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

So, to start with, you need to change the way that `tableInfo` is initialized, no longer will you need the `DefaultTableModel`, and instead you would use something more like...

```
tableInfo.setModel(new InterviewTableModel());
```

When you want to add a new `Interview` to the model, you could use something like...

```
InterviewPane editor = new InterviewPane();
switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmationDialog(this, editor, "Details", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)) {
    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
        Interview interview = editor.getInterview();
        InterviewTableModel model = (InterviewTableModel)tableInfo.getModel();
        model.addInterview(interview);
        break;
}
```

For example...

Comment: thank you so much for this codes.. i really appreciate it. but i am having an error on the :                                                                                               switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, editor, "Details", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)                                                        when i run my program, it says that showConfirmDialog is an error..  :)

Comment: by the way.. the codes that i had was all autogenerated by the use of Window Builder that i installed. I thought it would be easier that way though. :)

Comment: *"..autogenerated by the use of Window Builder that i installed. I thought it would be easier that way.."*  A GUI designer can be well used in the hands of a pro who already understands how the components work and how to lay them out.  For a newbie it just gets in the way of understanding and makes them unwilling or unable to adjust that magic-generated codez to their need.  Leave them aside for the moment..

Comment: @AngelfromSky As near as I can tell, it should work.  What's the error?

Comment: im sorry ..my mistake.. my next question are.. would i need to delete my current JTable and make a new one.. how would i do that?

Comment: You would need to make use of a custom `TableModel`, something that extended directly from `AbstractTableModel`, as this will allow you to manage the `Interview` objects directly, rather than needing to break the object apart for something like `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: So basically, I would need to delete the table on my main table and make another one using AbstractTableModel right?..

Comment: Not the table, just change the model that it uses

Comment: Thank you so much for these codes. All I need to do now is to interconnect these codes and put them on right place. Thanks. You've been a great help @MadProgrammer